# Is the simple tense better than the continuous tense in "When I lied to him, I crossed a line."?

Tags: tense

I am wondering about the tenses in this sentence.

> When I lied to him, I crossed a line.

I think "lied" and "crossed a line" are correct since the lying results in me crossing the line. Does the sentence make more sense if I use "crossing" like this:

> When I lie, I am crossing a line.

How does that differ from:

> When I lie to someone, I cross a line.

Again, I think the simple tense is better than the continuous tense, since the crossing is a result of me lying to someone.

Comment: "When I lie" is the simple present and indicates a general truth.  "When I lied" is the simple past and indicates something that happened in the past.  Neither one is "better"; they mean different things.  (Neither one is a continuous tense.  A continuous tense would be like "When I *am lying*...")

Comment: I meant if the sentence made more sense if I used: when I lie I am crossing a line. how does that differ from when I lie I cross a line.

Comment: I've tried to work your comments into your question - you may want to [edit] your question a bit more to be sure that it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Although the meaning is conveyed the more natural way to speak this sentence is "**I crossed a line when I lied to him**".

The more correct or natural form of the next sentence you've given will be: **"I cross a line whenever I lie to someone."**

If you want to say that **" 'X' happens whenever/every time you do 'Y'."** then you use the second form. If you want to say that **" 'X' happened because you did 'Y'. "** then you use the first form.

Comment: hello. what is the difference between "I am crossing a line when I lie to him." what is more natural? "I cross a line when I lie to him." or "I am crossing a line when I lie to him."?

Comment: All sentences you wrote are correct depending on the situation. All are natural if used in the correct place.